# Parsing a very particular string structure in ruby (baseball data)

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'm trying to write a small baseball statistics program using data from retrosheet.org, but I'm having trouble parsing their line score data. In a game where a team does not score double digits in any particular inning, their line score would look like this `001003000` (they scored 1 run in the third inning, and 3 runs in the sixth). If, however, a team scores double digit runs, the data will look like this `00100(10)000` (1 run in the third, and 10 runs in the sixth).

For now, I'm just trying to parse out the score for each inning and put it in an array. Here's what I have so far:

```
scores = %w{00100300800 32004300X 00(11)34000 0000(15)000X 0000(15)000(13) 10(18)47(11)8(10)3}

scores.each do |s|
  game = []
  if s.include? "("
    # HELP!
  else 
    s.each_char { |c| game << c }
  end
  puts game.join("+")
end
```

I'm sure the solution involves regex, which I'm terrible at, so I've been trying all sorts of terrible string manipulation methods. In the end, I think it's going to be better to just ask for help.

So, how would you guys do this?

Comment: I'd write a very tiny parser and not use regex.

Comment: Interestingly, the tiniest parser I could write was indeed [slower](https://gist.github.com/1828593) than regex.

Comment: @louism It might have performed faster if you had used the C-based [`StringScanner`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/strscan/rdoc/index.html).

Comment: @Phrogz, good to know. The performances of String#[] and String#each_char seem to be very bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can parse those with [`scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
s.scan(/\(\d+\)|\d/)
```

For example:

```
>> scores = %w{00100300800 32004300X 00(11)34000 0000(15)000X 0000(15)000(13) 10(18)47(11)8(10)3}
>> scores.each { |s| puts s.scan(/\(\d+\)|\d/).inspect }
["0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "3", "0", "0", "8", "0", "0"]
["3", "2", "0", "0", "4", "3", "0", "0"]
["0", "0", "(11)", "3", "4", "0", "0", "0"]
["0", "0", "0", "0", "(15)", "0", "0", "0"]
["0", "0", "0", "0", "(15)", "0", "0", "0", "(13)"]
["1", "0", "(18)", "4", "7", "(11)", "8", "(10)", "3"]
```

And then just strip off the parentheses and call `to_i`:

```
s.scan(/\(\d+\)|\d/).map { |s| s[/\d+/].to_i }
```

For example:

```
>> scores.each { |s| puts s.scan(/\(\d+\)|\d/).map { |s| s[/\d+/].to_i }.inspect }
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0]
[3, 2, 0, 0, 4, 3, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 11, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 13]
[1, 0, 18, 4, 7, 11, 8, 10, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
str = '00(11)34000'
str.scan(/\d{1}|\(\d{2}\)/).map { |a| a.gsub(/[()]/, '') }
# => ["0", "0", "11", "3", "4", "0", "0", "0"]
```

Here I get array like `["0", "0", "(11)", "3", "4", "0", "0", "0"]` and remove all `(` and `)`. I don't use complex regex here - it would be hard to read instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very small parser that accomplishes what you need:

```
scores = %w{00100300800 32004300X 00(11)34000 0000(15)000X 0000(15)000(13) 10(18)47(11)8(10)3}
games = []

scores.each do |s|

  game = []
  cs = s.split('')

  cs.each_with_index do |c,i| 
    if cs[i-2] == '('
      game[-1] += c
    elsif !(c == '(' || c == ')')
      game << c
    end
  end

  games << game

end
```

Note that its [slower](https://gist.github.com/1828593) than using regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Flipflopping:

```
str = "0000(15)000X"
tmp = ""
res = []
str.each_char do |c|
  if c=='(' .. c==')' #flip-flop, read like "If we are between '('and ')'.
    tmp << c
  else
   unless tmp.empty?
     res << tmp[1..-2] 
     tmp = ""
   end 
   res << c
  end
end
p res #=>["0", "0", "0", "0", "15", "0", "0", "0", "X"]
```